# IIS 8 express side by side with iis 7.5

Tags: iis

I have IIS 7.5 on my computer.  I want to deploy signalr web app, but it does not work with IIS 7.5 (after several hours of trying all the work arounds suggested on SO or MS KB).  Some one suggested to try IIS 8 express.  Can I have both installed on my computer?

Comment: You should be able to, only you won't be able to run both on the same IP:Port combination (by default IIS tries to bind to all IPs on port 80.) You would need to configure each to run on it's own Port if using 1 IP.

Comment: What OS are you using?